# Complex Array Comparison in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm programming a PHP quiz application and am having some trouble with the scoring mechanism. Specifically, I have 2 arrays that I'm comparing to determine if an answer is correct or not.

I want to verify that all values of one array are found in another array. For example, if the correct answer

```
Array
(
    [0] => Proprietary user community
    [1] => Surveys
    [2] => Voice
    [3] => Online chat
    [4] => Web
    [5] => Email
    [6] => Social media
)
```

And the user provided answer is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Surveys
    [4] => Online chat
    [6] => Email
)
```

The system return incorrect, because all correct values have not been provided. Similarly, if the user provided answer looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Proprietary user community
    [1] => Surveys
    [2] => Voice
    [3] => Online chat
    [4] => Web
    [5] => Email
    [6] => Social media
    [7] => Phone
    [8] => Live chat
)
```

The the answer would be correct, if though additional answers have been provided.

Any ideas? I've been thinking of using `array_intersect()` but there has to be a more elegant solution.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just intersect the arrays and compare sizes.

```
$answer_key = array(/* your answer key here */);
$user_answers = array(/* user answers here */);

$intersection = array_intersect($answer_key, $user_answers);

if (count($answer_key) === count($intersection)) {
    // winner, winner, chicken dinner
} else {
    // fail
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I knew it had to be possible with `array_intersect`

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using array_intersect()?

```
<?php
$arr1 = array("a" => "green", "red");
$arr2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");

$result = count(array_intersect($array1, $array2)) === count(arr1.count);
?>
```

Comment: This is not java or javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Array diff would be better for this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

```
if (empty(array_diff($correctArray, $userAnswers))) {
    // correct
} else {
    // incorrect
}
```